# Else statement still running when if statement is true with google script

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

I have a function that has a name with a set of data and this name is compared to a list of names. If that name is already in the list of names, the data associated with the name replaces the old data. If the name is a name not in the list of names it adds the name and the associated info to the bottom of the list.

For some reason when I run the code with a name already in the list, the original data is replaced and the name and data are added to the bottom of the list. I want to avoid repeating people while also adding new individuals.

````
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lookup = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Lookup");
  var issued = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Issued");
  var name1 = lookup.getRange(12,3).getValue();
  var info = lookup.getRange(16,3,1,12).getValues();
  
for (var j=1;j<105;j++){
    var issuedOfficers = issued.getRange(j,11).getValue();
//if the officers name is already recorded in issued the system will replace the current data with updated data
    if (issuedOfficers === name1){
      issued.getRange(j,1,1,12).setValues(info);
    } else {
      var lastrow = issued.getLastRow();
      issued.getRange(lastrow+1,1,1,12).setValues(info);
      break;
    }
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

In your script,

- When `j` is `1` and `issuedOfficers === name1` is `true`, `issued.getRange(j,1,1,12).setValues(info)` is run. And, when `j` is `2` and `issuedOfficers === name1` is `false`, `issued.getRange(lastrow+1,1,1,12).setValues(info)` is run. And the for loop is finished.
- When `j` is `1` and `issuedOfficers === name1` is `false`, `issued.getRange(lastrow+1,1,1,12).setValues(info)` is run. And the for loop is finished.

I think that this is the reason of your issue. In order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for (var j=1;j<105;j++){
    var issuedOfficers = issued.getRange(j,11).getValue();
//if the officers name is already recorded in issued the system will replace the current data with updated data
    if (issuedOfficers === name1){
      issued.getRange(j,1,1,12).setValues(info);
    } else {
      var lastrow = issued.getLastRow();
      issued.getRange(lastrow+1,1,1,12).setValues(info);
      break;
    }
}
```

To:

```
var names = issued.getRange(1, 11, 105, 1).getValues().flat();
var index = names.indexOf(name1);
if (index > -1) {
  issued.getRange(index + 1,1,1,12).setValues(info);
} else {
  issued.appendRow(info[0]);
}
```

- In this modification, at first, the values are retrieved from the sheet of `issued`, and it checks whether `name1` is included in the values. By this, the row is updated or the value is appended.

#### Note:

- Please use this script with enabling V8.

#### References:

- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)